# How to use graphviz dot notation in php?

Tags: php, graphviz

I'm just wondering if anybody help me know how to use graphviz dot notation in php?

UPDATE:
or how can I add a code like bellow directly in my php file ?

```
digraph dfd2{
        node[shape=record]
        subgraph level0{
        enti1 [label="Customer" shape=box];
        enti2 [label="Manager" shape=box];
        }
        subgraph cluster_level1{
                        label ="Level 1";
                        proc1 [label="{<f0> 1.0|<f1> One process here\n\n\n}" shape=Mrecord];
                        proc2 [label="{<f0> 2.0|<f1> Other process here\n\n\n}" shape=Mrecord];
                        store1 [label="<f0>    |<f1> Data store one"];
                        store2 [label="<f0>   |<f1> Data store two"];
                        {rank=same; store1, store2}

        }
        enti1 -> proc1
        enti2 -> proc2
        store1 -> proc1
        store2 -> proc2
        proc1 -> store2
        store2 -> proc1 
}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you need integration with graphviz lib, which, in my experience, is not so easy to configure.
Maybe using only javascript: https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/
(example of use in http://blog.pnkfx.org/blog/2015/10/12/viz-a-viz-js/)